# Match from string to first comma in vim

Tags: regex, search, vim

I need to search and replace a string beginning with cmc and ending with the **first** occurrence of a comma on the line. I've tried several iterations of `/"cmc.*,\{-}` and `/\("cmc\).*\(,\=\)` and everything in between to no avail (and searched far and wide for the past week). Sample desired result:

**"cmc":2,**"colors":["Black"],

instead of what I get now:

**"cmc":2,"colors":["Black"],**

I want it to match to that first comma, but instead it matches to the very last comma on the line. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `/"cmc.\{-},`

If you use `*`, it matches the longest possible occurence; on the opposite, `\{-}` matches the shortest one.

`*` and `\{-}` always refer to the very last atom preceding it; an atom can be a simple letter, or a dot `.` char, or a complex pattern enclosed with `\(` and `\)`...

See `:h pattern-overview` for more explanations

Another common way to do such searches is to search for "everything but a comma", with the following syntax: `[^,]`, so another answer for your question would be: `/"cmc[^,]*,`

Comment: Ah, yes. I never realized `\{-}` was an expansion and could be used in place of `*`. Genius. Thanks so much.